# Error: A value of type 'Iterable<Transaction>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'List<Transaction>?'. showing this error

Tags: flutter

```
List<Transaction>? get _recentTransactions {
  return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
    assert(tx != null);
    return tx.date.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7),),);
  });
 }
```

when  I am doing this it is showing this error can anyone explain

Comment: Could you post the error message you are referring to as well?

Comment: It's in the title

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `where` function in Dart return you an `Iterable<T>` and not a `List<T>`.

But since you have the return type of your function as `List<Transaction>`, you have to convert the `Iterable<Transaction>` that you are getting from the `where` function.

For this use the, `toList` function on the `Iterable`.

```
List<Transaction>? get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
        assert(tx != null);
        return tx.date.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7),),);
    }).toList();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a list by .toList

```
  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
        return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
           
            return tx.date.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7),),);
        }).toList();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `Iterable<String>`

A value of type 'Iterable<String?>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Iterable'. I used .cast like that

```
customerNames.where((String? option) {
          return option!
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        }).cast()
```